# Why might my Admob requests be much bigger than my impressions?

Tags: admob, ads, impressions

My ad-mob app's ads requests are up to 700 but my impression are only up to 300, what problem am I facing? Is there an application fault?

Here is a picture:

[image: example]

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087333/admob-account-showing-big-difference-in-matched-requests-and-impression-due-to-a)

Comment: What does this have to do with requests?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham nothing. =)

Comment: no issue with requests. Add a country filter to see what county/city has requests but dropped impressions. Use multiple ad request to fill add requests